# Nodejs path.resolve is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
// codenotworking

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
log = console.log;
const names = [];

function collectFileNamesRecursively(path) {
  fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
    err ? log(err) : log(files);

    // replacing paths
    for (const index in files) {
      const file = files[index];
      files[index] = path.resolve(path, file);
    }
    for (let file of files) {
      fs.stat(file, (err, stat) => {
        err ? log(err) : null;
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
          collectFileNamesRecursively(file);
        }
        names.push(file);
      });
    }
  });
}
collectFileNamesRecursively(path.join(__dirname, "../public"));
```

i am using nodejs v10.8.0 and the directory stucture is

```
 - project/
 -     debug/
 -         codenotworking.js
 -     public/
 -        js/
 -            file2.js
 -        file.html
```

whenever i run this code i get the following error

TypeError: path.resolve is not a function
    at fs.readdir (C:\backup\project\debug\codenotworking.js:17:24)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:139:20)

what am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're [shadowing](https://simpletutorials.com/c/2239/Variable+Shadowing+in+JavaScript) your `path` import by specifing the `path` parameter in `collectFileNamesRecursively`. Change the parameter name to something else.

Apart from that using recursion with callbacks this way won't work - I would recommend using `async/await`. Something like:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

async function collectFileNamesRecursively(currBasePath, foundFileNames) {
    const dirContents = await fs.promises.readdir(currBasePath);

    for (const file of dirContents) {
        const currFilePath = path.resolve(currBasePath, file);
        const stat = await fs.promises.stat(currFilePath);
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            await collectFileNamesRecursively(currFilePath, foundFileNames);
        } else {
            foundFileNames.push(file);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how did I not notice this. I am just a beginner thanks